# How to throw a warning or error in terraform plan?

Tags: terraform

I am currently writing a terraform custom provider for my internship project

The main aim of the project is to provision an environment (consisting of several servers) on a private cloud platform.

I created a custom provider using the CRUD operations.

Let's say I want to delete the whole resource by removing the whole resource block in main.tf. I want to do a `terraform plan` to see if the deletion is valid. It will do a read of the actual environment and see if the serverState of the server is active. I want it to throw a warning/error in `terraform plan` is serverState is not empty.

So the main issue right now is that the `terraform plan` only compares the difference between the configuration in main.tf and the actual tf statefile. So the error checking code in the delete function is not executed. It is only executed when `terraform apply` is used.

Is there any way to throw the error in terraform plan to warn the user before they use the `terraform apply` command

Comment: Terraform typically shows red text of "resource will be replaced". You want an extra warning on top of that? I don't think you want the provider to do this as the user of the provider can set [prevent_destroy](https://www.terraform.io/language/meta-arguments/lifecycle#prevent_destroy) on any resources necessary.

Comment: I am not trying to replace the resource. I allow the user to delete the resource. What I am want is to throw a warning in terraform plan if the condition for deletion is not met.